# Can't find my VM instance (Debian) in Google Compute Root user and Super user Password

Tags: django, debian, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, mezzanine

In my VM instance I have username the same as my email address (without @gmail.com). It is created automatically, and I do not know the password for it. Also, another user which is a root user,and I do not know the root password.

I need it because when I try to run

```
fab secure
```

it will ask me for the password whether I'm running it using a root user or another superuser.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

By default, there are no passwords; everything is done using certificates. If you use [SSH in the browser (by clicking the SSH button in Cloud Console)](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser), everything is handled for you. Simply `sudo whatever` (`sudo fab secure`, for your example) and you're done.

If you'd like to SSH using an SSH client, [here's](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys) what you'll need to know.

By default, everyone who can log in to an instance can use `sudo`; if that's not what you want, you can use the new [OS Login](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#enable_oslogin) feature, which allows you to allow users shell access to the instance without being able to use `sudo`).

By default, [the root user is disabled and can't be used](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#root), and you don't need to use it; if you require a root shell (instead of executing individual commands as root) then `sudo su -` is what you're looking for.